# Browser extension to disable the pop-up window when I click on a Google +1

Tags: web-browser, chrome

I'm annoyed by the pop-up window that appears whenever I click on a Google +1:

[image]

I am looking for a browser extension (ideally Chrome) to disable the pop-up window when I click on a Google +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey that means I can recommend [Adblock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/en) twice today!

AdBlock Plus (ABP) is a browser extionsion for pretty much any browser; here's a few details:

- *Open source:* Yes.
- *Gratis:* Yes.
- *No 'dial home' features:* auto-updating is the norm for Firefox extensions; that can be disabled in Firefox; Adblock Plus also has filter lists that can be set to auto-update but that can be disabled as well. Other than those two caveats as far as I know ABP doesn't have any dial home functions.
- *A simple GUI allowing adding new/editing existing regex'es in the browser*: I'd say it is pretty simple and easy.
- *Whitelist regexes:* Yep white listing is done
- *Ability to fire certain blacklist/whitelist regexes based on the main document's address (e.g. allowing Google APIs on one site and disallowing it on others).* *hmmm...* ah [Yes you can](https://adblockplus.org/en/filters#elemhide_domains).

Specifically in your case; to block the Google+ bubble just add a custom filter: 
`##.gc-bubbleDefault`
like this:
[image]

Comment: Works great, thanks! This means I can upvote you twice :)